# PdfMake in java script

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

How create border radius of below image in pdfmake javascript, or table with cruse shape for below image, actually the below image is in table, i want curve for that image, if any border radius in pdfmake js,  if you now please help me,

```
var dd = {

    content: [

                                {
                        style: 'tableExample',
                        table: {
                                headerRows: 1,
                                body: [
                                        [{ 
                                            image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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',
                                            corners: [1,11,10,10]
                                        }],

                                ],

                        },
                        layout: {
                                                        hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
                                                                return (i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length) ? 2 : 1;
                                                        },
                                                        vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
                                                                return (i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length) ? 2 : 1;
                                                        },
                                                        hLineColor: function(i, node) {
                                                                return (i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length) ? 'black' : 'gray';
                                                        },
                                                        vLineColor: function(i, node) {
                                                                return (i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length) ? 'black' : 'gray';
                                                        },

                                                        // paddingLeft: function(i, node) { return 4; },
                                                        // paddingRight: function(i, node) { return 4; },
                                                        // paddingTop: function(i, node) { return 2; },
                                                        // paddingBottom: function(i, node) { return 2; }
                        }
                }
    ],
    styles: {
        header: {
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: true,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 10],

        },
        subheader: {
            fontSize: 16,
            bold: true,
            margin: [0, 10, 0, 5],


        },
        tableExample: {
            margin: [0, 5, 0, 15],


        },
        tableHeader: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 13,
            color: 'black',

        }
    },
    defaultStyle: {
        // alignment: 'justify'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you converted the image to base64  ?

in the following thread is a similar problem: [Image not showing when generating pdf in angularjs using pdfmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647253/image-not-showing-when-generating-pdf-in-angularjs-using-pdfmake)

Comment: is there any border radius in the pdfmake js

Comment: this is the only listing i could find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291112/pdfmake-api-is-there-a-list-of-styles-fonts-capabilities try it on http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

Comment: please tell me how create table as cricle by using tableBorder element

Answer (score 4):

i got an answer to my question, i think, it will useful for others

```
    canvas: [
                        {
                            style: 'rectangleData',
                            type: 'rect',
                            x: 198,
                            y: -186,
                            w: 198,
                            h: 188,
                            r: 8,
                            lineWidth: 4,
                            lineColor: '#276fb8',

                        },
]
```